# Apache- свой http код при обработке 404

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

Есть хостинг, сайт, .htaccess со строкой

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

и файл 404.php, который разбирает URL и отдает

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");  (ну или другие статусы, если надо).

Но приходит всегда 404. Страница открывается как надо, но код-то не 200, а 404!  В чем может быть причина такого поведения? Может Apache сам слать 404, а потом уже мой обработчик вызывать? На других хостингах стоит куча сайтов с таким механизмом и все прекрасно работает. Тут же фигня какая-то. Техподдержка шлет какие-то отписки,то куки виноваты, то модреврайт попробуйте.

Какие настройки Apache надо смотреть?

Comment: А при чём тут nginx?

Comment: nginx не использует файлы .htaccess, вы туда хоть сагу напишите, ему фиолетово.

Comment: Вы у техподдержки выясните сначала, что у вас на хостинге - nginx или Apache.

Comment: И то верно..  затупил..  Apache.

Comment: Nginx просто в заголовке ответа приходит, я на нем и зацилилися что-то..

Comment: Как в заголовке ответа может приходить nginx, если стоит Apache?

Comment: Прсото. Стоят в паре. Nginx пересылает запросы Apache, кешированием занимается.

Comment: @KAGGDesign так делает большинство shared-хостингов и сайтов на пхп

Comment: А, ну да, встречал такое.